# How do I reset to my source code on heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, version-control, github

I've deployed an app to heroku and want to reload that source code and work from there again and blow away all changes I've made since.  Is there a way to do a git reset --head [heroku-source]?  I know I can get the source with a `heroku git:clone -a myapp`but I would like to know if there's a more efficient way.

After I pushed to Heroku, I kept making changes and never pushed to Git.  So my cleanest code is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your changes are all on the `master` branch, and you have that branch checked out before you start.

1. Make sure you have a Heroku git remote:

   ```
   heroku git:remote
   ```
2. Check out a new branch, so that you don't lose your changes if something goes wrong:

   ```
   git branch recent-changes
   ```
3. Fetch from the Heroku remote, this will create or update a remote tracking branch called `heroku/master` that contains the current state of the master branch on Heroku:

   ```
   git fetch heroku
   ```
4. Look at what's changed between `master` and `heroku/master`, and make sure you really want to throw those changes away:

   ```
   git log heroku/master..master
   ```
5. Reset your local `master` branch back to wherever the `heroku/master` branch is up to:

   ```
   git reset --hard heroku/master
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply

```
git reset --hard heroku/master
```

where `heroku` is the name of the heroku remote origin. You can view your remote branches with

```
git branch -r
```